# how to create an API with GraphQL on top of Hive?

Tags: api, hive, graphql

I'm trying to create an API with **GraphQL** on top of **Hive**, has anyone done something of the sort?

Thanks

Comment: @Sarah Aziziyan have you people found any ideas on this

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this for the past week.  I've gotten close to it working by leveraging Graphene, Graphene-SQLAlchemy, and PyHive but the queries aren't generating in a way that Hive likes (due to aliasing of the columns by Graphene-SQLAlchemy is my suspicion).

It definitely looks possible - just need to figure out this last bit and it should work.